# RoR - how to update facebook status with RoR?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook

sorry, if my english so bad..
i created a simple auction app with RoR. in my app, if i create a new auction, i want my facebook status update with the new auction that i have created. how to do that?

nb: this is not facebook app.

what should be required? oauth? help me please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you won't be able to do this on the back-end unless your user has added your Facebook application and given you extended permissions (the right to update status on their behalf). Otherwise you'll need to make a facebook connect using one of their APIs. Here is an example using Javascript to make a stream.publish update.

```
function callback (post_id, exception) { if(post_id) { post_to_my_server(post_id); } 
Facebook.streamPublish('', attachment, null, null, 'What do you think?', callback);
```

http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Facebook.streamPublish

Answer (score 0):

And here you go one using http: 
http://ggomeze.com/2011/05/19/post-to-facebook-from-rails-app